# How to repartition into fixed number of partition per column in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I need to read data from one hive table and insert it into another Hive table. The schema of both the tables is the same. The table is partitioned by date & country. The size of each partition is ~500MB. I want to insert these data in a new table where the files inside each partition are roughly 128 MB (i.e 4 files)

Step 1: Read data from the source table in Spark.

Step 2: Repartition by column(country, date) and the number of partitions to 4.

```
df.repartition(4, col("country_code"), col("record_date"))
```

I am getting only 1 partition per country_code & record_date.

Comment: hive supports partitioning by values only. Calculate new column with required distribution and repartition by it. Or add more keys to the partitioning to increase the number of partitions

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you are doing in the step 2 will repartition your data to 4 partitions in the memory but it won't save 4 files if you do df.write.

In order to do that you can use below code:

```
df.repartition(4, col("country_code"),col("record_date"))
.write
.partitionBy(col("country_code"),col("record_date"))
.mode(SaveMode.Append).saveAsTable("TableName")
```